# How to get the id and show the next field on the basis of that id in ror?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails4. I want to show the sub-category list based on a category which is being selected in a form. I have done with java-script but I think its not a good solution. Please suggest me what should I do?

I want the user to select a category from this

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Category %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { :prompt => true, :selected => @product.category_id } %>
</div>
```

After this next field will get updated based on the user selection. Currently I have made hidden these #women_category & #men_category

```
<div class="field" id="women_category">
  <%= f.label :sub_category %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select  :sub_category_id, @first_category.sub_categories.all,:id ,:name%>
</div>
<div class="field" id="men_category">
  <%= f.label :sub_category %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select  :sub_category_id, @second_category.sub_categories.all,:id ,:name%>
</div>
```

Now when user selects category_id=1, I display the #women_category and if user selects category_id =2, #men_category is displayed with the help of javascript

```
$("select[name='product[category_id]']").change(function(){  
  if(this.value == '1'){
    $("#women_category").show();
    $("#men_category").hide();
  }else if(this.value == '2'){
    $("#women_category").hide();
    $("#men_category").show();
  }
});
```

If my categories list increases it will be complicated, So I can I code this without this much complications? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the controller

```
@categories = Category.include(:sub_categories).all
```

In the view

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :Category %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, { :prompt => true, :selected => @product.category_id } %>
</div>  

<div id="subcategory-selects">
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <div class="field sub-category-select" data-category-id="<%= category.id %>" style="display:none;" disabled="disabled">
      <%= f.label :sub_category %><br>
      <%= f.collection_select  :sub_category_id, category.sub_categories,:id ,:name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$("select[name='product[category_id]']").change(function(){  
  //get the subcat select with this category id, show and undisable it, and hide and disable its siblings
  $(".sub-category-select[data-category-id="+$(this).val()+"]").show().removeAttr("disabled").siblings().hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

The reason i'm disabling/undisabling the subcategory selects, as well as hiding/showing them, is that even if they are hidden, they still contribute to params when the form is submitted.  Because they all have the same name attribute, the last one would effectively override the others.  Disabled inputs, on the other hand, do NOT contribute to params, so it's only the visible & undisabled one that will actually contribute to params.

Note - a field is deemed "disabled" if it has the attribute "disabled".  The value of the attribute doesn't need to be set to "disabled" - it makes no difference in fact.  I just like to set the value to disabled as it makes it very obvious.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion. But include was showing error- "wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)"... I tried with includes, error has gone. But on selecting category, subcategory field are not showing up. Why are they still hidden?

Comment: this is the error showing up in console- "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .sub-category-select[data-category-id=function (a){var b,c,d,e=this[0];{if(arguments.length)return d=m.isFunction(a),this.each(function(c){var e;1===this.nodeType&&(e=d?a.call(this,c,m(this).val()):a,null==e?e="":"number"==typeof e?e+="":m.isArray(e)&&(e=m.map(e,function(a){return null==a?"":a+""})),b=m.valHooks[this.type]||m.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()],b&&"set"in b&&void 0!==b.set(this,e,"value")||(this.value=e))});if(e)return b=m.valHooks[e.type]|..

Comment: Hey I got this error removed by replacing "$(this).val" by "this.value", now console is not showing up with any error , but its still not dispalying the subcategories. Why .show() is not working?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `.val()` instead of `.val`

Comment: Ok!! i will do that let me check :)

Comment: Never mind, just spotted another error in the markup.  Should be fine now.

Comment: The error was that i'd added another class attribute, like this: `class="field" class="sub-category-select"`.  When you do this it will just take one of them, usually the first, so the sub-category-select class wasn't present.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Hey @max , Please have a look on this query also. If you can help, it would be grateful.-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871447/how-to-change-attribute-name-in-flash-for-nested-models-attribute